# How to Write an LLVM Pass in C

Tags: c, llvm

I am trying to write an LLVM Pass in C, but I can only find information on how to do this in C++. If anyone has any references or knowledge on this topic, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you!

Comment: You can't. LLVM is designed around C++, not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [llvm-c-kaleidoscope](https://github.com/benbjohnson/llvm-c-kaleidoscope) where you can learn by example how to use the [llvm-c interface](https://github.com/earl/llvm-mirror/tree/master/include/llvm-c).